# Finding the domain and range of a composite function f(g(x)) with fraction and trig

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am trying to solve this problem. This is what I have done:

ATTEMPT 1: I have tried to think about the domain using composite functions but ended up no-where.

ATTEMPT 2: Restricting the domain for the f(x) and g(x)

ATTEMPT 3: Graphically; but this does not show any proof of finding the domaing and range

**Question**: Find the domain and range of f(g(x))

Given the following:
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{x^2+1}{2x^2-1}\right)$$
$$g(x)=2\pi-\arccos(x)$$
$$f(g(x))=2\pi-\arccos \left(\frac{x^2+1}{2x^2-1}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2+1}{2x^2-1}=\frac12+\frac3{2(2x^2-1)}.$$

As $2x^2-1\ge-1$, the range of $f(x)$ is $(\frac12,\infty)\cup(-\infty,-1]$.

So intersecting with the domain of the cosine, $g\left(\left(\dfrac12,1\right]\cup\{-1\}\right)=\left(\dfrac{5\pi}3,2\pi\right]\cup\{\pi\}$.

Answer (score -1):

If $|2x^2 - 1| \leq 1$, then the fraction $\frac{x^2+1}{2x^2-1}$ has value outside $[-1,1]$ and hence the function is not defined. Thus the domain is $|x| \geq \sqrt{2}$.

When $|x| \geq \sqrt{2}$, the fraction takes all values in the range $\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right]$. Thus $arccos\left(\frac{x^2+1}{2x^2-1}\right)$ takes all values between $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $0$. Thus the range is $\left(2\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}, 2\pi\right]$

Comment: $\frac12$ is not in the range of $f$, and $g(f(0))=\pi$.

Comment: Yes, corrected.